# PHP associative array undefined index error

Tags: php, associative-array

Trying to get a grip on arrays in PHP.

The code :

```
$filename = "/path/file.csv";
$importer = new CsvImporter($filename,true);
$data = $importer->get();
var_dump($data[2]);
```

The above returns the following output:

```
array(19) {
["▒▒Time"]=>
string(33) "2016-12-21 19:00"
["Entry"]=>
string(115) "HKLM\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Office\Outlook\Addins"
...
```

When trying to access the value in key "Entry"

```
var_dump($data[2]["Entry"]);
```

I get undefined index error and I just cant figure out what Im doing wrong.
Browsing through several examples here I just cant get it to work...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: just `var_dump($data)` to see what is inside data. Sounds like [2]['Entry'] isn't there.

Comment: The output is then the following:

`[198]=>
  array(19) {
["▒▒Time"]=>
string(33) "2016-12-21 19:00"
["Entry"]=>
string(115) "HKLM\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Office\Outlook\Addins"`

Comment: Might be some invisble character. "Time" looks a little weird as well. Could you please add the output of `var_dump(array_keys($data[2]))`. That way we can see the lengh of the keys.

Comment: Yes youre right, time has some strange chars there. Here is the output:

`array(19) {
  [0]=>
  string(10) "▒▒Time"
  [1]=>
  string(29) "Entry"`

Thanks.

Comment: That means you need save the csv file in a different encoding. But I don't know much about those. If you can live without the keys you could uses `array_values($data[2])[1]` to get the entry. But it might get confusing as your project grows.

Comment: Great, that worked fine! In this project I can live without the keys, no problem. Thank you for helping me out!